# Attempting to use two arrays as variables to search file names (powershell)

Tags: arrays, powershell, copy

I need to search multiple (named) folders on multiple servers for files matching a specific date and copy those files to a local folder using Powershell.  The number of folders are not the same size arrays as the number of servers.  I.e. I need \server1\interfacefolders\folder1, \server1\interfacefolders\folder2, \server2\interfacefolders\folder1, \server2\interfacefolders\folder2, etc.

I have the following set up as arrays/variables preparing for this, I thought "nested" foreach loops would work, but it bombs out...any ideas how to get started on this?:

```
[string[]]$ProdServerArray = "server1", "server2", "server3" 
[string[]]$InterfaceArray = "folder1", "folder2" "folder3" do {
$date = Read-host "Enter date (MM/DD/YYYY) : " } while ($date -as [datetime] -isnot [datetime]) 
$date = $date -as [datetime]

$destination = new-item c:\GetFilesResults\$($date.toshortdatestring().replace("/","-")) -type directory

$path = foreach ($ProdServer in $ProdServerArray) 
{   
    $folder = foreach ($Interface in $InterfaceArray)   
    {
    $file = "\\$path\InterfaceFolder\$folder\*"
    if ("$file".LastWriteTime -gt $date.date)
        {
           Copy-Item -Path $file.fullname -Destination $destination
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

to build the full folder names from those two arrays, you can use two nested `foreach` loops. once you have the values, you can build the paths via something like the `-f` string format operator.

i left out the rest of your code since it does not appear to pertain to the question you asked. [*grin*]

```
$ProdServerArray = 'serverAAA', 'serverBbBbBb', 'server_CCC'
$InterfaceArray = 'folder1', 'folder2', 'folder3', 'folder666'

foreach ($PSA_Item in $ProdServerArray)
    {
    foreach ($IA_Item in $InterfaceArray)
        {
        '\\{0}\InterfaceFolders\{1}' -f $PSA_Item, $IA_Item
        }
    '=' * 30
    }
```

output ...

```
\\serverAAA\InterfaceFolders\folder1
\\serverAAA\InterfaceFolders\folder2
\\serverAAA\InterfaceFolders\folder3
\\serverAAA\InterfaceFolders\folder666
==============================
\\serverBbBbBb\InterfaceFolders\folder1
\\serverBbBbBb\InterfaceFolders\folder2
\\serverBbBbBb\InterfaceFolders\folder3
\\serverBbBbBb\InterfaceFolders\folder666
==============================
\\server_CCC\InterfaceFolders\folder1
\\server_CCC\InterfaceFolders\folder2
\\server_CCC\InterfaceFolders\folder3
\\server_CCC\InterfaceFolders\folder666
==============================
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you are missing a comma in the line:

> [string[]]$InterfaceArray = "folder1", "folder2" "folder3"

Additionally, as far as I can tell, your do while loop doesn't appear to be accomplishing anything, as the only time this will ever be true is if the time 12:00:00AM exactly on the date specified. No matter what date you input in the format (MM/DD/YYYY), they will not be equal unless the case I said above.

Since you are searching multiple servers, Invoke-Command is your friend, as a foreach loop will act in series, while this will work in parallel. It will send out the search command to each server simultaneously.

I am not quite sure exactly what you are trying to do, so I did not fill in the actual search code(seen below), but the part i have left blank would be where you enter what filename/filename schema you are looking for. If you provide more clarity I can assist further if needed.

(Note: **$filepath**, although self explanatory, is the file paths you wish to search. You can generate them in a way similar to the one provided by **Lee_Dailey**. I'd recommend removing the divider lines and saving the paths generated to a **String System.Array Object**)

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ProdServerArray -ScriptBlock {Get-Childitem –Path $filepath -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |where {<your code here>}}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't run remote powershell on these servers due to security permissions, and the command has to run locally.
What I need to do is gather xml files from a single day (say 1/16/2020) for a rollback plan on a system upgrade.  So "\\$ProdServerArray\InterfaceFiles\$InterfaceArray\*.*" (matching create/modify date of 1/16/2020) copied to a local path like "C:\Results\$ProdServerArray\InterfaceFiles\$InterfaceArray\*.*"